# Angular cropped image file size become bigger

Tags: javascript, angularjs, image

I'm using this plugin [angular-image-cropper](https://github.com/AllanBishop/angular-img-cropper) to crop my image and [ng-file-upload](https://github.com/danialfarid/ng-file-upload) to upload my image.

The problem is let say my image dimension is 1955px * 1300px with size around 194kb.

After I crop to 800px * 450px the size become around 550kb.

is this correct? because it become almost 4 times bigger from it's original size

my html code:

```
<div class="form-group">
     <label class="control-label">Cover</label>
     <input type="file" ngf-select="uploadFiles($files,$invalidFiles)" name="cover" id="cover" ngf-pattern="image/*" accept="image/*"
       ng-model="upload.coverSource" ngf-max-size="512KB" ngf-min-width="800" img-cropper-fileread image="upload.coverSource"
       disable-invalid-styling="true" disable-valid-styling="true">

      <canvas ng-show="upload.coverSource" width="500" height="281" id="canvas" image-cropper image="upload.coverSource"
        cropped-image="category.coverCrop" crop-width="800" crop-height="450" keep-aspect="true" crop-area-bounds="bounds">
      </canvas>
</div>
```

Inside my angular I just tried to console.log both of them:

```
console.log($scope.upload.coverSource);

// and i need to convert it to blob first to get the data.
// category.coverCrop value is in data:base64

var cover = Upload.dataUrltoBlob(category.coverCrop);
console.log(cover);
```

Here is the result screenshot:

[image: screenshot]

Any solution to make the size same or lesser?

Answer (score 0):

In most of the croppers that I've tested, the resulting image gets translated into a raw format making it bigger, in the case of your info, look that the image is in its raw base64 format, also here is an example of a pretty advanced editor that has a similar result: https://www.photoeditorsdk.com/ the thing is that compresion or any further processing is a different task than cropping, and is not usually handled by this libs; so how you solve it? In our case, we integrate with cloudinary.com and use their transformation API to make sure all our images has the right size and quality.

Answer (score 0):

in image- cropper change format type from png to jpeg  (this may give size near to it but not exactly same size)

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).